# Integral representaion of confluent hyper-geometric function

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function

How can I prove these two integrals are equivalent ($\alpha,\beta, z>0$):
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^\infty t^{\beta-1}(1+t)^{-\alpha}e^{-zt} dt,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}(z+t)^{-\beta}e^{-t} dt.
\end{equation}
The first is a representation of the Confluent HG function, and the later can be transformed to the first. I tried the usual real transformations but none worked. Any hints are very much appreciated.